# QAbstractItemModel::removeRow does not delete records in related tables

Tags: sqlite, qt5

Qt5.14.0, sqlite3.
I create two tables:

```
CREATE TABLE manufacturing (pn TEXT PRIMARY KEY, model TEXT NOT NULL, sn TEXT, FOREIGN KEY (pn) REFERENCES settings (pn) ON DELETE CASCADE ON UPDATE CASCADE);

CREATE TABLE settings (pn TEXT NOT NULL, name TEXT NOT NULL, value TEXT, PRIMARY KEY (pn, name));
```

In the `settings` table I have some records like these:

```
abc|foo1|11
abc|foo2|22
abc|foo3|33
def|foo1|11
def|foo2|22
def|foo3|33
```

and in table `manufacturing`:

```
abc|model1|123
def|model2|234
```

In my application I created two `QSqlTableModel`s to display data on `TableView`s:

```
_modelManufacturing = new QSqlTableModel(this, QSqlDatabase::database("dbData"));
_modelManufacturing->setTable("manufacturing");
_modelManufacturing->select();
ui->tableManufacturing->setModel(_modelManufacturing);

_modelSettings = new QSqlTableModel(this, QSqlDatabase::database("dbData"));
_modelSettings->setTable("settings");
ui->tableSettings->setModel(_modelSettings);
```

by the way, I filter the second table as needed:

```
_modelSettings->setFilter("pn=\"" + ui->linePN->text() + "\"");
_modelSettings->select();
```

Now I delete a row in the `manufacturing` table:

```
_modelManufacturing->removeRow(ui->listDb->currentIndex().row());
```

because I've set the `ON DELETE CASCADE` flag I'm expecting also the records in `settings` table with the same `pn` should be deleted. Instead they are not affected.

Why? How to automatically delete them whenever I remove the corresponding record in the first table?

### UPDATE

Here how I open the db:

```
bool ManagerDatabase::openDatabase(QString name)
{
    QString filename = qApp->applicationDirPath() + "/" + name + ".sqlite";
    if (!QFile::exists(filename)) return false;

    QSqlDatabase db = QSqlDatabase::addDatabase("QSQLITE", "dbData");
    db.setDatabaseName(filename);
    bool ret = db.open();
    if (ret) enableForeignKeys();
    return ret;
}

void ManagerDatabase::enableForeignKeys()
{
    QSqlQuery query(QSqlDatabase::database("dbData"));
    query.prepare("PRAGMA foreign_keys = ON;");
    query.exec();
}
```

Comment: Set `PRAGMA foreign_keys = ON` because its default value is `OFF`.

Comment: I've already set it to ON, question update.

Comment: Actually, I discovered this error: `QSqlError("1", "Unable to execute statement", "foreign key mismatch - \"manufacturing\" referencing \"settings\"")`. Perhaps is there something wrong with my keys?

Comment: See my answer....

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> ...because I've set the ON DELETE CASCADE flag I'm expecting also the
>   records in settings table with the same pn should be deleted...

You misunderstood what `ON DELETE CASCADE` does.
What you should expect is that if a row in `settings` is deleted then all the rows in `manufacturing` that hold a reference of the column `pn` of the deleted row in `settings` will also be deleted and not the other way around.
So the deletions on the parent table cascade to the tables that hold references of the columns in this parent table.
You can find more [here](https://www.techonthenet.com/sqlite/foreign_keys/foreign_delete.php).

Comment: Yes, I just swapped the constrants.